# How to convert uint8 byte array to string in Java

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have an unint8 byte array which a function from a library is returning the library is cross compiled from golang using gomobile, Golang has byte arrays of type unint8,

The byte array is

```
[4, 19, 35, 76, -77, -6, 106, -70, -95, -37, -58, 2, 20, 94, 34, -73, 79, 69, -84, -90, 30, 27, 125, -102, -116, 105, 52, 89, -62, 116, -92, 27, -56, 98, -124, 42, -2, -109, -30, -101, -60, -12, -103, 28, 26, 46, -54, -33, 61, -17, 115, 39, -14, -15, -60, -109, -119, -106, -128, 95, 65, 84, 12, -56, -76]
```

I want to convert this byte array to string in java

I know you can convert byte to string using new String()

but when I convert the byte array I get random characters as

♦‼#L��j����☻¶^\"�OE��▲��i4Y�t�b�*�����∟→.��=�s'��ē���_AT♀ȴ

Comment: did you check what was the input string?

Comment: The input string is a public key derived from a key pair which can be as ```d5f8b59cc5606f653083c14458284328f46c91f98be3a5cc6521052e7b3c1c2d``` and the string whose byte array is generated can be as ```0x04127a7a32bc31691052781ec6b37ebfe841d9ca12b08fb5ebd8fb391d437dad2f70fe367104006418e846577866428ea61dc2e720799ecf2dce0affcabfe5749e```

Comment: String input = "d5f8b59cc5606f653083c14458284328f46c91f98be3a5cc6521052e7b3c1c2d";

        byte[] bytes = input.getBytes();

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bytes));

        String output = new String(bytes);

        System.out.println(output); // prints d5f8b59cc5606f653083c14458284328f46c91f98be3a5cc6521052e7b3c1c2d    there is something else n between like some other transformation

Comment: this is the byte array for input string [100, 53, 102, 56, 98, 53, 57, 99, 99, 53, 54, 48, 54, 102, 54, 53, 51, 48, 56, 51, 99, 49, 52, 52, 53, 56, 50, 56, 52, 51, 50, 56, 102, 52, 54, 99, 57, 49, 102, 57, 56, 98, 101, 51, 97, 53, 99, 99, 54, 53, 50, 49, 48, 53, 50, 101, 55, 98, 51, 99, 49, 99, 50, 100] using above method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure, what is your expected output. This function would print out something like:

> 010203041B1A

```
public class ByteUtils {

private static final char[] HEX_ARRAY = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray();
private static final int MASK_BYTE_SIZE = 0xFF;
private static final int MASK_SECOND_TUPLE = 0x0F;
private static final int SHIFT_FIRST_TUPLE = 4;

public static String bytesToHexString(final byte... bytes) {
    if (bytes == null || bytes.length == 0) {
        return "";
    }
    final char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];
    for (int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++) {
        int v = bytes[j] & MASK_BYTE_SIZE;
        hexChars[j * 2] = HEX_ARRAY[v >>> SHIFT_FIRST_TUPLE];
        hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = HEX_ARRAY[v & MASK_SECOND_TUPLE];
    }
    return new String(hexChars);
}
}
```

Comment: My output should be something as ```0x04127a7a32bc31691052781ec6b37ebfe841d9ca12b08fb5ebd8fb391d437dad2f70fe367104006418e846577866428ea61dc2e720799ecf2dce0affcabfe5749e```

Comment: Basically this code should work for you. Maybe you need to adopt the `HEX_ARRAY` variable using non-capital letters.